# Windows 10 not an option for GRUB Boot Menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

So this has been a wild ride of a day, I started by trying to remove Ubuntu, messed up and removed GRUB, tried to fix it using a Windows 10 repair loaded onto a USB, that didn't work, reinstalled Ubuntu, discovered that GRUB was no longer loading. So I looked around found the Boot-Repair tool, used it. Now I have GRUB but it only lists UBUNTU and Advanced UBUNTU Options.

Link to my `fdisk -l` and `parted -l` results https://pastebin.com/XW6k8bta

Comment: I know I didn't delete window's because I can still access all the windows file's from inside Ubuntu. They're all sitting there inside the OS, but I cannot boot. I will try the first comment to see if I am accidentally posting a duplicate issue.